# Qt QML WebEngineView default tooltip is displayed incorrectly in the html content

Tags: html, qt, qml, tooltip, qwebengineview

So I have Qt 5.12 and my project is based on the QML language. I am using the Nano Browser example, but I modified it to my extent.

Now, as I have been customizing it, I noticed that, for example, at www.google.com, the default tooltip when you hover over the input text to search, the tooltip's background appears as yellow, with black text... not only that, but the text shows after the rectangle that's supposed to be centered in.

I have updated all modules to the maximum version. I have searched far and wide with no solution available to me.

The problem persists on all platforms.

I am using the Nano Browser example provided by the Qt Creator IDE. Even with the default code, the problem is still present.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFe5M.jpg "Google Chrome"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/faiqZ.jpg "Custom"

Comment: Apparently looking at the image we have to guess what HTML/CSS code is used here ...

Comment: It's www.google.com. No custom HTML, CSS or JS.

Comment: @user4136548 Were you able to customize tooltip style in QML WebEngineView? I have the same problem, if you did please update the question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I didn't and I gave up. :(